# Flagging invalid cells makes it impossible to Undo

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I have some cells with validation, but invalid data can be entered into cells by pasting it.  When a user pastes data into a cell, I would like to turn the cell red if the data is invalid, or restore it to white if the data is valid.

I'm using the following worksheet event:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

If Not target.Validation.value Then
    target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
    target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End If

End Sub
```

This performs the required color change, but it also makes it impossible to Undo.  Is there any way to implement this type of cell coloration while still allowing the user to Undo paste actions?

Comment: Would conditional format not do the same for you?

Comment: @PaulFrancis, indeed it would.  I'm going to implement a conditional formatting rule using an  `is_valid()` function similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20959389/619177).  Feel free to post this as an answer if you like.

Comment: This may be overkill, but I also had a requirement to stop in cell validations being over written by users pasting.  I found this piece of code that uses the undo queue to change a paste into a paste special, whihc preserves any in cell validation [link](http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2009/04/macros-in-excel-disable-cut-copy-paste.html)

Comment: undo is disabled after code execution. You would have to save the value somewhere and restore it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per PaulFrancis' answer, I was able to accomplish this using conditional formatting.